# My program prints more than 1 sentence, want it to print only one sentence

Tags: c

I have a problem with my program

The first problem is if I feed in the sentence containing more than 3 words it will print e.g. "Hey there, how are you?" it prints, I think 100 words. But when I write sentences that contain less than 3 words, it works as it should. and I wonder if you would check what I have done wrong.

My question is how should I change/make it so it only prints one line instead of 100.

I am new to programming and English is not my mother tongue.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define SIZE 100

int main(void) 
{

    char arr[SIZE];
    char* p = NULL;
    

    do {

        int count = 0;
        printf("Enter a sentence:");
        fgets(arr, SIZE, stdin);
        for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
            if (arr[i] == ' ') {
                count++;
            }
        }
        if (count < 3) {
            printf("The sentence is to short!\n");
        }
        else {
            count = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
                if (arr[i] == ' ') {
                    count++;
                }
                if (count == 2) {
                    p= &arr[i + 2];
                }
                printf("%s\n", p);
            }

        }
        return 0;
    } while (1);
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do in that second for loop? If you just want to print the sentence why not just replace that whole else case with `printf("%s\n", arr);`?

Comment: A loop that just returns at the end of the first iteration doesn't serve much purpose.

Comment: Can you show us an example - what's your input, what's the output, and what's the output you're expecting?

Comment: This how it should be: Enter a sentence: input  Welcome to the course in programming
output: the course in programg.  The problem with my program is it output: the course in programg like 30+ times, but it should only output only one sentence instead of 30+

Comment: Based on code, if input is: `abc def ghi jkl mno pqr`, you want to print `ghi`???

Comment: Yes! craig Estey.    the problem I will have is that it will print like 40+ such ghi, but I want it to print only one ghi.

Comment: @hacker2000 The loops like this for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) { do not make a sense. You should parse a string stored in the array not all the array.

Answer (score 1):

A few issues:

1. You always do the `printf` even if `p` is `NULL`, so you'll segfault
2. If we fixed that, you are *not* splitting the sentence into words, so you'll print the remaining part of the line
3. Once you start printing, you never stop.

Much better to split into words using `strtok`.

Here is the refactored code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define SIZE 100

int
main(void)
{

    char arr[SIZE];

    int count = 0;

    printf("Enter a sentence:");
    fgets(arr, SIZE, stdin);

    char *bp = arr;
    while (1) {
        char *cp = strtok(bp," \n");
        bp = NULL;

        if (cp == NULL)
            break;

        if (++count == 2) {
            printf("%s\n",cp);
            break;
        }
    }

    if (count < 2)
        printf("The sentence is to short!\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: ok, when ok when I tried to run your program an error message came up :
Error C4996 'strtok': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using strtok_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. ???

Comment: @hacker2000 You're on windows. Please accept my condolences :-) `strtok` is a standard function. Either change the code to use the Windows specific (non-standard) `strtok_s` or use the `_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS`. I recommend using the standard function `strtok` and suppress the warnings. Or, better yet, install linux and do the coding there.

Answer (score 0):

```
fgets(arr, SIZE, stdin);
for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
```

`SIZE` is good for dimensioning the array and as a parameter to `fgets()` informing the function of the maximum size of the array. Once the input is returned, however, you only want to deal with the *leading region* of the buffer (up to the terminating '\0'); not the full length of the buffer.

Beyond that, the "flow control" is quite mixed up. Too much happening without a clear sequence of what is being checked and when things are being used (*invoked*).

The title, the question and the code make it unclear if you want to print everything after the *skipped* leading words, or just the next word after skipping.

`strtok()` has its place, but the string passed must be 'mutable' (meaning that strtok will replace some characters with '\0'; the original string buffer will be lost.) An advantage of `strtok()` is that several different separators can be specified, and one-or-more separators appearing together are dealt-with as if there were only one at that location.

To "fine-tune" this operation, and retain the original string buffer, here is a bit of code that only 'sniffs-at' the string buffer looking for single SPs separating "words". The final print statements show that the buffer remains unaffected. This can be useful when *substrings* of a *string literal* are to be retrieved.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define SIZE 100

int main( void ) {
    char arr[SIZE], *p = NULL;
    int skip = 1; // skip one word

    for( ;; ) {
        printf( "Enter a sentence: ");
        fgets( arr, SIZE, stdin );

        p = arr;
        while( skip >= 0 && (p = strchr( p, ' ' ) ) != NULL )
            skip--, p++;

        if( p && strchr( p, ' ' ) )
            break;
        puts( "The sentence is too short!" );
    }

    putchar( '\n' );

    printf( "Rest of sentence: %s", p );

    printf( "Next word only: " );
    while( *p && *p != ' ' )
        putchar( *p++ );
    putchar( '\n' );

    printf( "Whole sentence: %s", arr );

    return 0;
}
```

```
Enter a sentence: /* pressed ENTER */
The sentence is too short!
Enter a sentence: the
The sentence is too short!
Enter a sentence: the quick
The sentence is too short!
Enter a sentence: the quick brown fox

Rest of sentence: quick brown fox
Next word only: quick
Whole sentence: the quick brown fox
```